# Anchor tag onclick around img tag not working in iphone iOs 9

Tags: javascript, ios, image, onclick, anchor

I have created a web page and added 2 links `<a onclick="">` around image tags `<img>`, this seems to work fine on all operating systems and devices, except for iOS Mobile 9. Can some one please help me in the issue?

I have already tried to add the style `cursor: pointer` to the link and also tried to put onclick in `<img>` tag but none of it works.

Since I don't have a MAC OS machine, I am not able to troubleshoot the issue as it can be replicated only on iPhone iOS 9 devices.

Page : http://www.zebrify.com/qr_events/141?qrhash=c2691670cfe74ba90b2ef7fe3b1dc0bf0e0eae61_EVT_141

Answer (score 0):

Make Anchor display:inline-block; its working then. worked for me.